# Improving runtime of function in Matlab using raspberry pi package

Tags: matlab, runtime, raspberry-pi3

We are using Matlab to control our raspberry pi 3 using the raspberry pi package.
we use this following code to rotate a stepper motor 100 steps:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

rpi1 = raspi;

cam1 = cameraboard(rpi1,'Resolution','1280x720');

pul_x = 5;
dir_x = 6;
ena_x = 12;

configurePin(rpi1,pul_x,'DigitalOutput');
configurePin(rpi1,dir_x,'DigitalOutput');
configurePin(rpi1,ena_x,'DigitalOutput');

writeDigitalPin(rpi1,pul_x,0);
writeDigitalPin(rpi1,dir_x,1);
writeDigitalPin(rpi1,ena_x,0);

for i = 1:100
    tic
    writeDigitalPin(rpi1,pul_x,1);
    pause(0.00005);
    writeDigitalPin(rpi1,pul_x,0);
    pause(0.00005);
    toc
end
```

Our computer connected to the network with lan cable, and the raspberry pi connect to the same network with lan cable aswell.
most of the time when we run this code the whole for loop takes around 40msec average, and there are sometimes that it takes around 8msec average but we are not sure why.
we think maybe it's because the network communication, and maybe there is other way to connect the computer and the raspberry pi to make the runtime faster but we are not sure how to do this.

We would like to get some advices about how to connect them directly, or if there are other suggestions we'll be glad to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MATLAB is not real time. There is no assurance that an specific function will take specific time to run. You can test this with absolutely any MATLAB fiction (no need of a raspberry pi). Run a chosen function 100 times and time  it. You will see that sometimes it takes more time than other times.

Comment: The runtime we wrote (40msec or 8msec) is the average of the whole for loop, we are aware that each line in the command line of the runtime will be a little different.

Comment: If each time is different, then the total time can be different, no? Maybe you are watching youtube videos in the background and the OS needs more time to do other stuff than run MATLAB. This is how computers work. There exist some real-time software that make sure that things are run before X ms, and I have used them in Simulink in the past. Not sure if MATLAB has this for what you are triying to do

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, what we meant is that when the runtime is 40msec each loop takes around 40msec (+-2msec). when we run Matlab we made sure that nothing else is running in the backround.

Answer (score 0):

In the hardware setup screen for [MATLAB Supportpackage for Raspberry Pi](https://in.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-matlab.html?requestedDomain=), you can select the option "**Connect directly to host computer**". 
[Refer this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufGb9.png)
This will create a direct connection between Pi and your PC. Once this is done, you will be able to access the Pi using the IP 169.254.0.2 (Only from your PC)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, we succeed to connect the raspberry pi to the host computer but it didn't improved the runtime.